# weak bounded sequences have weak convergent subsequences

Tags: functional-analysis

I have to prove the statement:
In a hilbert space, weak bounded sequences have weak convergent subsequences.

Maybe somebody could help me with some idea, I don't really know how to start with that problem.

Comment: Perhaps this follows from Banach-Alaoglu?

Comment: One can show that if a Banach space  $X$ is reflexive, then the closed ball is compact in the weak topology.

Since every Hilbert space is reflexive, I think it's done.

For more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_space#Properties